# How are Daily trading indicators calculated for current day?

Tags: calculation, algorithmic-trading, moving-average

New to algo-trading, so I wonder, how are the trading indicators, based for instance on daily close prices, calculated during the current day (in progress)?
I mean for a 14 SMA on Day period, the 14th value to use in calculations is the current price of the current day? Or the current day's price will only be used in calculations when the current day ends?
Because the 50 day SMA may cross above the 200 day SMA during the day (so the algo might decide to go long), but at the end of the day, it might end up below it, so the order should have not been triggered at all?
And if the price is included only at the end of day, that means all algos react and place orders at exactly 00:00 GMT?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this, an indicator on daily candles will use the current day's price, only after the day closes:

> The most recent green candle has no SMA, because the trading day is not over yet and, respectively, there is no closing price.

Found it on [Tradingpedia](https://www.tradingpedia.com/forex-trading-academy/simple-moving-average/)